# What is another, specific word for being full from food?

Tags: synonyms

I'm not really satisfied with what the thesaurus is giving me. Full, stuffed, and satiated don't quite taste right in the context I'm using. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about _overfed_?

Comment: Gorged might fit.

Comment: Tell us more about the context which this word must fit into.

Comment: What is the context you are using?

Comment: dv because the question is poorly asked and doesn't explain why the synonyms of the question are not appropriate for the non-existent context.

Comment: @SrJoven I didn't say that *any* of the user-suggested synonyms were not appropriate. Can you think of a synonym for the word *assumption*? In the future, you may want to allow OP to reply before throwing a hissy fit.

Comment: I didn't say that the user synonyms were not appropriate, either. I said that the synonyms of the question, that you wrote, didn't explain why they were not good answers in the context that you didn't provide.

Comment: Feel free to modify your question and ask in [meta] to have it reopened, if you feel you can improve the question. My comment was 12 hours after you posted, and 4 hours after the last request for context was posted.

Answer (score 5):

The word 'sated' would be a good fit. 
It's the past tense of 'sate' which means

> to satisfy (any appetite or desire) fully.

or

> to fill to excess; surfeit; glut.

Answer (score 1):

Replete: OED 2.B.: “Filled to satisfaction with food or drink; sated, full; gorged. Freq. with *with;* formerly also with †*of.”*