# Word that means having eaten one's fill

Tags: single-word-requests

Full can be mistaken for a description of a whole as opposed to a part.
For example:

> "The [full] frog hopped back to its lily-pad."

Can be understood as:

> "The frog [that had eaten recently and was no longer hungry] hopped back to its lily-pad."

or:

> "The frog [no longer a tadpole or other "pre-frog" stage] or [not a piece of the frog but the whole frog] hopped back to its lily-pad.

What is a way of saying someone or something is "full" without that possible misunderstanding?

Comment: One does need to be wary.  In Norwegian "full" (which has the same general meaning as in English) means "drunk" when applied to a person.

Comment: related: [Word, idiom or expression to describe feeling full (after eating)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32420/word-idiom-or-expression-to-describe-feeling-full-after-eating/32433#32433) and [What is another, specific word for being full from food?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207088/what-is-another-specific-word-for-being-full-from-food/207092#207092)

Comment: Well, one could always say that the frog had "pigged out" on bugs or whatever.

Comment: Heh. A frog, that "pigged" out.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One word you could use is “[sated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sated)": ( from M-W)

> - having one's appetite completely satisfied:
>
>   - the sated baby fell instantly to sleep.

Comment: That's the word .....Sometimes you're so hungry you feel like you could eat a ten-course meal. Other times it takes just a small salad to sate your appetite.

Comment: Is there any noticeable difference between using _sated_ and _satiated_?

Comment: I think that "satiated" has a more "filling" feel to it.

Comment: My gastronomic rapacity knows no satiety (sorry - had to).

Comment: Perhaps a bit to close to _mated_ for a frog context?

Comment: I think "sate" and "sated" is probably more technically correct, but I never hear/see it used - normally people say "satisfy" and "satiated" instead.

Comment: I think satiated is more useful as an adverb than an adjective.  "he was satiated by the meal" for example.

Answer (score 15):

You could say that the frog is *[replete](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/replete)*:-

> Filled to satiation; gorged. [American Heritage Dictionary via The
>   Free Dictionary]

or

> having one's appetite completely or excessively satisfied by food and
>   drink; stuffed; gorged; satiated [Collins English Dictionary via The
>   Free Dictionary]

Comment: You are not answering the question. The asker asked "The [xxx] frog hopped back to its lily-pad". Can you verify your answer by saying "The repleted frog hopped back to its lily-pad" ? I'm not wasting a downvote on your answer, though it deserves one.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, I'm not sure I understand your objection; one would say _The replete frog..._.

Comment: The synonyms "stuffed" and "gorged" given are also very good candidates for the original question.

Comment: This sounds more than full to me.

Comment: _The stuffed frog..._ So many meanings! Taxidermy, incredibly tired, etc. The two best words from your answer are _replete_ and _sated_ / _satiated_.

Answer (score 7):

You could say that the frog is *satisfied*, and let the user connect the frog's satisfaction to the meal you previously described: *The satisfied frog hopped back to its lily pond.*

You could use *fully* or *totally* satisfied to emphasise that the frog had eaten all that it desired.

Comment: One could also use the word to say: _Satisfied with his meal, the frog hopped back to its lily-pad._

Comment: (Otherwise, _satisfied_ could be a bit ambiguous as he may have just returned from an intense [froggystyle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndQZBQJf034) lovemaking session)

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to re-word the sentence to avoid the misunderstanding.

> "Engorged with flies, the frog hopped back onto its lily-pad".

*Not speaking to the question, but I've always enjoyed the term 'frolicking bog-hopper' for frog.*

Comment: If he can still hop, he's not very good at gorging himself.  Also, moderate me to hell if you must, but plus one for *frolicking bog-hopper*.

Answer (score 5):

I personally enjoy the slang:

> [Stuffed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stuffed) ***v*** 4. To cram with food

Although *"The stuffed frog"* wouldn't necessary sound the best here.  Better in an application like *"I am stuffed"*

Comment: Would that be [stuffed frog](https://www.google.com/search?q=stuffed+frog&tbm=isch) or [stuffed frog](http://www.coborns.com/Recipes/RecipeFull.aspx?RecipeID=48911)?

Answer (score 3):

This seems a more familiar to me than "sated":

Satiated: Verb (used with object), satiated, satiating.

1.to supply with anything to excess, so as to disgust or weary; surfeit.

2.to satisfy to the full; sate.

-[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satiate)

Answer (score 2):

As it's one of my favourite phrases, I'm honour-bound to share the following:

- to have had an ample sufficiency.

In this case:

- Having had an ample sufficiency, the frog hopped back to its lily-pad.

Comment: its, not it's! (SE won't let me edit that because the change is less than 6 characters...)

Comment: Isn't there some redundancy in 'ample sufficiency'?